# Windows 10 - timeout to boot normaly not available in selection on start

Tags: windows-10, boot, safe-mode, normal-mode

We have an issue with one computer, acting pretty much in kiosk mode. When a computer starts after an unsuccessful power off, Windows goes to the option to boot normally or to safe mode. Usually, on every other computer, it automatically selects "boot normally" and after 20s timer runs out, it boots to Windows without any problem.

But on one computer **it's missing timer completely** and it waits for user confirmation, so ***we have to manually press Enter on a keyboard*** (that is permanently present behind the kiosk, hidden in the box).
I'm not entirely sure how is this possible, as all other computers are pretty much the same model and all OS with the same settings were deployed directly on drives from same image.

I could not find any reasonable online so far.

Comment: "after an unsuccessful power off," Please explain with details?

Comment: By that I mean sometimes computer hangs in middle of shutting down and powelines are shut before it's able to turn off completely. We run big exhibition science center, so there are various computers with slight differences (beefed up grafic card, or extra sound card, network adapter) bit most they're pretty same. So all other PCs are able to boot normally, even when they're shut off before they can finish proper shutdown procedure, except for this one.